# Hibernate Sequence Combined With Insert Statements Not Working

Tags: sql, hibernate, insert, sequence

I previously had a table that is created using hibernate entities.  I am using the hibernate import.sql method to input a bunch of data to run before my unit tests.  These are all in insert statements.

Everything was working fine until a design change forced us to switch to using a generated PK instead of the old NaturalId PK.  Now none of my inserts are working and hibernate is not spitting out any errors.  Please help!

```
@Entity
@Table(name="PERSON")
@GenericGenerator(name="PERSON_SEQ", strategy = "sequence",
 parameters = { @Parameter(name="sequence", value="PERSON_SEQ") } )
public class PersonEntity implements Serializable {

@Id 
@GeneratedValue( strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="PERSON_SEQ")
@Column(name="PERSON_ID", nullable=false, updatable=false)
private Long id;

@NaturalId
@NotNull
@Min(1)
@Column(name="FIRST_NAME", nullable=false, updatable=false)
private String firstName;

//More code....
```

And for my insert statements...

```
INSERT INTO "PERSON" (PERSON_ID, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, SOCIAL_SECURITY) VALUES (PERSON_SEQ.NEXTVAL, 'John', 'Doe', '111111111');
```

I could care less if inserting via creating a hibernate object works in this case.  It's much more important that the sql insert statements work.

Also, I have hibernate set to INFO and show sql is true, but still no error messages...  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: "Not working" isn't an error description. Are you getting ORA errors?

Comment: I see no ORA errors in my logging.  The rows are simply not being inserted.

Comment: Even not when you are executing the INSERT statement by hand?

Comment: Ok, nevermind, I figured it out.  I am getting an error on the insert statement now.  Could not execute bulk manipulation query.  I am inexperienced tho.. just running session.createSQLQuery('sqlfromabove').executeUpdate();

Comment: Can you show me the results of these two SQL statements? `select PERSON_SEQ.NEXTVAL from dual;` and `select max(person_id) from person;`. If the second value is bigger than the first, then the inserts can't work.

Comment: System.out.println(sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createSQLQuery("SELECT PERSON_SEQ.NEXTVAL FROM dual;").uniqueResult());

I ran that code.  The result was "could not execute query".  My worry here  (and has been all along) is that hibernate is not properly creating the sequence.

Comment: "that hibernate is not properly creating the sequence." - Note: You need to create the sequence yourself, Hibernate doesn't create the sequence if you are not recreating the complete schema with the help of hibernate.

Comment: @Craig: I meant, please execute the two queries in an SQL utility like sqlplus or SQLDeveloper. There these statements should work. (I think you're using Oracle.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue here has to do with me unit testing in Hypersonic.  I am not sure if any of you are familiar with that but that is the unit testing sql dialect my team is using.  Thanks for the comments.  I've been able to solve me issue by doing the following work-around:

Hardcode the id for certain columns with 1 for the first value and then select max(id) + 1 for each subsequent column.  After all data is inserted I then increment the sequence to the proper value with the help of PL/SQL.

Thanks for your help everyone.

Answer (score 2):

You can also insert fixed numbers (i do it to make teh FK to other tables) and in the end of your import.sql add a command to alter your sequence. Like this:

```
insert into person values (1, 'John');
insert into person values (2, 'Pedro');
insert into person values (3, 'Junior');
ALTER SEQUENCE hibernate_sequence RESTART WITH 15;
```

Check the Oracle sintax to do the same.

Comment: Works fine on Oracle 12 ;) Thanks